# how can I vertically center a span in a div?

Tags: html, css

I really would like this and have been trying for hours, I have it centered horizontally in the div but just need to get it vertically centered now..

This is my css code for the span thats horizontally centred in a div.

```
  .titl {

    font-family:serif;

    text-align:center;

    font-size:35px;
    font-weight: bolder;

    color:#FFFFFF;

    padding-top:1cm;
      text-shadow: 0 0 2px #000; /* horizontal-offset vertical-offset 'blur' colour */
    -moz-text-shadow: 0 0 2px #000;
    -webkit-text-shadow: 0 0 2px #000;

  }
```

This is the html of div code:

```
<div class="wrapper">

<div id="Production" class="orange" style="cursor:wait">

    <div id="incidentsList">

        <span class="titl">Production</span>


    </div>
</div>





<div id="Infrastructure" class="red" style="cursor:wait">

    <div id="requestsList">
<span class="titl">Infrastructure</span>

    </div>
</div>





<div id="QA" class="green" style="cursor:wait">

    <div id="approvalsList">
<span class="titl">QA</span>

    </div>


</div>

</div>
```

The css code for the orange and red etc is below:

```
.orange {
    background-image: url('../images/nFinal.jpg');
    background-position: bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 120px;
    width: 224px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 2px;
    TEXT-ALIGN: center;
}
```

EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT
EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT*********************************
@Dan I tried what you said but it didnt work.
HTML:

```
  <div id="Productiond">

            <span class="titl">text</span>


    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#Productiond {height: 50px}




 .titl {

    font-family:serif;

    text-align:center;

    font-size:35px;
    font-weight: bolder;

    color:#FFFFFF;

    padding-top:1cm;
      text-shadow: 0 0 2px #000; /* horizontal-offset vertical-offset 'blur' colour */
    -moz-text-shadow: 0 0 2px #000;
    -webkit-text-shadow: 0 0 2px #000;
    height: 50px; 
    line-height: 50px;
  }
```

Comment: Not to sound snotty, but this has been asked a few hundred times -- look at http://tutorialzine.com/2010/03/centering-div-vertically-and-horizontally/ for a few approaches.

Comment: I tried on google and some threads I read people misunderstood and helped with aligning horizontally and others said it wasn't possible. I know of centering a div inside a div but can't find even on SO centering a span vertically and horizontally in a div
PS: the link you posted is of centering a div horizontal and vertical. However, it doesnt talk about centering a div inside a div

Comment: Here's a working sample of my example below: http://jsfiddle.net/2qnHu/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try setting the height of the `.titl` span to match the height of the enclosing `div` tag. then setting the `line-height` of the `.titl` span to match that as well.  this would work depending on the context you are using it in.

Try this for an example:

HTML:

```
<div id='Request'>
<span class='titl'>Test Message</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#Request {height: 50px}
.titl {height: 50px; line-height: 50px}
```

This would then display the title "Test Message" centered vertically inside the containing Div.

Comment: it did not work for me dont know why but I got it working by adding 2 <br />....Since your example works in the fiddle and would probably be helpful for someone else I think its considered an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

First, I would recommend removing the `padding`, `height` and `line-height` declarations from `.titl`. Then, I would specify `vertical-align: middle` on `.titl`. `vertical-align` is meant for inline elements, and `span`s are inline elements. Thus, you can use `vertical-align`.

That said, I was unable to duplicate your issue when attempting it on JSFiddle and JSBin. If this does not solve your issue, I would recommend posting a link to one or the other.